# A package that I am using is not working in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, math

I basically got this package where it is suppose to calculate the standard deviation for me. However, when used it does not work. I am new to javascript so anything will help. Thankyou!

```js
function standardDeviation(values) {
  var avg = average(values);

  var squareDiffs = values.map(function(value) {
    var diff = value - avg;
    var sqrDiff = diff * diff;
    return sqrDiff;
  });

  var avgSquareDiff = average(squareDiffs);

  var stdDev = Math.sqrt(avgSquareDiff);
  return stdDev;
}

function average(data) {
  var sum = data.reduce(function(sum, value) {
    return sum + value;
  }, 0);

  var avg = sum / data.length;
  return avg;
}

function myfunction() {
  var stdDev = standardDeviation([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 25]);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = stdDev;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<button <button onclick="myFunction()">Try Me</button>
```

Comment: What exactly is or isn't working? Immediately, I see `<button <button onclick="myFunction()">Try Me</button>` should be `<button onclick="myFunction()">Try Me</button>`

Comment: You are calling `myFunction` but your function is `myfunction`, so it is just a case typo

Answer (score 0):

Guy pointed out I am terrible at spelling and that I make obvious typos. Should be myfunction() to match with myfunction()